# Binding SelectedItems of ListView to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a list view that binding items with a property in viewmodel.

```
<ListView Height="238" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Name="listView" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="503"
          ItemsSource="{Binding BusinessCollection}"
          SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />  
                       </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and in viewmodel.

```
ICollectionView _businessCollection

public ICollectionView BusinessCollection
{
    get { return _businessCollection; }
    set {
          _businessCollection = value;
          RaisePropertyOnChange("BusinessCollection");
        }
}
```

How to get selected item of businesscollection in viewmodel?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**1. One way to source binding:**

You have to use `SelectionChanged` event. The easiest way is to     write eventhandler in codebehind to "bind selecteditems" to viewmodel.

```
//ViewModel
public ICollectionView BusinessCollection {get; set;}
public List<YourBusinessItem> SelectedObject {get; set;}

//Codebehind
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewmodel = (ViewModel) DataContext;
    viewmodel.SelectedItems = listview.SelectedItems
        .Cast<YourBusinessItem>()
        .ToList();
}
```

This still aligns with MVVM design, because view and viewmodel resposibilities are kept separated. You dont have any logic in codebehind and viewmodel is clean and testable.

**2. Two way binding:**

if you also need to update view, when viewmodel changes, you have to attach to ViewModel's `PropertyChanged` event and to the selected items' `CollectionChanged` event. of course you can do it in codebehind, but in this case I would create something more reusable:

```
//ViewModel
public ObservableCollection<YourBusinessItem> SelectedObject {get; set;}

//in codebehind:
var binder = new SelectedItemsBinder(listview, viewmodel.SelectedItems);
binder.Bind();
```

or can create custom attached property, so you can use binding syntax in xaml:

```
<ListView local:ListViewExtensions.SelectedValues="{Binding SelectedItem}" .../>
```

```
public class SelectedItemsBinder
{
    private ListView _listView;
    private IList _collection;


    public SelectedItemsBinder(ListView listView, IList collection)
    {
        _listView = listView;
        _collection = collection;

        _listView.SelectedItems.Clear();

        foreach (var item in _collection)
        {
            _listView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void Bind()
    {
        _listView.SelectionChanged += ListView_SelectionChanged;

        if (_collection is INotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            var observable = (INotifyCollectionChanged) _collection;
            observable.CollectionChanged += Collection_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    public void UnBind()
    {
        if (_listView != null)
            _listView.SelectionChanged -= ListView_SelectionChanged;

        if (_collection != null && _collection is INotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            var observable = (INotifyCollectionChanged) _collection;
            observable.CollectionChanged -= Collection_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void Collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems ?? new object[0])
        {
            if (!_listView.SelectedItems.Contains(item))
                _listView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems ?? new object[0])
        {
            _listView.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems ?? new object[0])
        {
            if (!_collection.Contains(item))
                _collection.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems ?? new object[0])
        {
            _collection.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Attached property implementation

```
public class ListViewExtensions
{

    private static SelectedItemsBinder GetSelectedValueBinder(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (SelectedItemsBinder)obj.GetValue(SelectedValueBinderProperty);
    }

    private static void SetSelectedValueBinder(DependencyObject obj, SelectedItemsBinder items)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedValueBinderProperty, items);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueBinderProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedValueBinder", typeof(SelectedItemsBinder), typeof(ListViewExtensions));


    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValuesProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedValues", typeof(IList), typeof(ListViewExtensions),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedValuesChanged));


    private static void OnSelectedValuesChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs value)
    {
        var oldBinder = GetSelectedValueBinder(o);
        if (oldBinder != null)
            oldBinder.UnBind();

        SetSelectedValueBinder(o, new SelectedItemsBinder((ListView)o, (IList)value.NewValue));
        GetSelectedValueBinder(o).Bind();
    }

    public static void SetSelectedValues(Selector elementName, IEnumerable value)
    {
        elementName.SetValue(SelectedValuesProperty, value);
    }

    public static IEnumerable GetSelectedValues(Selector elementName)
    {
        return (IEnumerable)elementName.GetValue(SelectedValuesProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. You should also handle collection reset in Collection_CollectionChanged method.

Comment: You might have written confused code that your class name is ListViewXxx but the implementation is ListBoxXxx.

Comment: I added handling of Reset in CollectionChanged method.

Answer (score -4):

Since the itemSource is BusinessCollection, you should be able to:

```
var selectedItems = BusinessCollection.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
```

Wrap it as a property on your VM.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but BusinessCollection don't have IsSelected Property.

Comment: Sorry didn't check that. Why not used a different collection then? With ObservableCollection, I know it works because I have implemented it like that before.

Comment: This has nothing to do with binding.