# Update controller from OnCollectionChanged method in a static dependency property class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, data-binding

I'am trying to create a `dependency property` that allows me to two way bind a datagrid it's selected items to an property in my viewmodel.

So far i got it to work one way, when the selected item is changed in the datagrid my collection is updated, but thats where i ran into a snag

```
public static class MultiSelectorHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SelectedItems",
        typeof(IList),
        typeof(MultiSelectorHelper),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnSelectedItemsChanged));

    public static IList GetSelectedItems(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (IList)element.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItems(DependencyObject element, IList value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selector = (Selector)d;
        var newList = e.NewValue as IList;
        var obs = newList as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        obs.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        selector.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dependency = (DependencyObject)sender;
        var items = GetSelectedItems(dependency);
        // items.Add/items.Remove
    }

    private static void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update current datagrid selected items .add/.remove
    }
```

When the collection changes it throws me into the `OnCollectionChanged` method, but from there i got no way to update my datagrid.

I have tried a couple of things, the first thing i tried was to define the event directly in the `OnSelectedItemsChanged` by means of `obs.CollectionChanged += (s, e2) => {all the code}` which altho works due to the access of `d` it resulted in triggering when the datagrid made a change to the collection with no way to disable it.

Another method i tried was to add an extra parameter to my `OnCollectionChanged` by means of `obs.CollectionChanged += (s, e2) => OnCollectionChanged(s, e2, d);` But this also did not get me any further and basicly resulted in the same issues as the one above.

The last thing i tried/could find/could come up with was to use a `PropertyChanged` event in my `OnCollectionChanged` and fire it off for each item that had changed, this in the hopes to be able to trigger the UI to send out an event i could hook into and update from there (since it would contain a dependency object of the datagrid). This never worked, no events never triggered anything leaving me at a dead trail.

The question is as follows, How would i be able to set the selected items of a datagrid (or any MultiSelector/Listbox) when a change is made from for example a viewModel, it's not a simple 1 on 1 binding so it does require having an instance of the controller to change it.

For those wondering, the idea is that it doesnt work for just a datagrid, but an object that is a ListBox or of type MultiSelector, for that reason i'm not just extending but creating a completely separate `dependency property`.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31178953/1136211

Comment: There is also a bug in your code. In OnSelectedItemsChanged, you must check if `e.NewValue` actually implements INotifyCollectionChanged, like `var obs = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged; if (obs != null) { ... }`. Also don't forget to detach the event handler from `e.OldValue`.

Comment: @BlackLotus: What exactly is your issue here? Getting a reference to the `DataGrid`?

Comment: @Clemens, i did, it seems that in that sample the controll (listbox in that case) is stored in a local variable to which he can reference when the CollectionChanged fires, since mine is static, and might be implemented multiple times by Listboxes, Datagrids etc im not sure i can really store that inside of my dependency class?

Comment: It's not a local variable, but a member variable of the SelectedItemsBinder class.

Comment: @mm8, correct once the collection is updated from code behind it fires off my OnCollectionChanged event, notifying me that a change has been made, since Datagrid's and listboxes etc don't normally have support for binding to a selected collection i need to update the selection manualy like datagrid.SelectedItems.Add(myItem) or datagrid.SelectedItems.Remove(myItem). But with the way im currently doing it i don't see how to get a hold of my controller to make these changes. (basicly a flaw in my design which i don't know how to resolve).

Comment: @Clemens, i see what you mean now, i asume that the backend code that creates the SelectedItemsBinder could instead be done in the OnSelectedValuesChanged, since it would only trigger on the initial binding? this would remove some of the overhead and allows for usage to just simple bind and forget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a local function that captures the selector:

```
private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selector = (Selector)d;
    var obs = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (obs != null)
    {
        void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataGrid = selector;
            //...
        }

        obs.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

The local function feature was introduced in C# 7.0. In earlier versions, you could use an anonymous method:

```
NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = (sender, ee) =>
{
    var dataGrid = selector;
    //..
};

obs.CollectionChanged += handler;
```

Comment: Looks very good, but it does result in the same issue i had with 2 of the methods i had already tried, which again, might have more to do with a flaw in my design.
When the OnSelectionChanged fires of (due to a selection change in the datagrid) it edits the collection, which then in turn would trigger the OnCollectionChanged event, technicly this wouldnt harm the results but seems like something to avoid. Normaly i would call  if (col != null) col.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged; before making edits, which doesn't work with it being a local function (if im not mistaking)

Comment: I don't understand your issue. What doesn't work within a local function? The only difference between a local function and an external event handler in this case is that the former is able to capture variables.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to explain it better. There are 2 event handlers in use.
The OnCollectionChanged which updates the datagrid with new changes and the OnSelectionChanged which updates the collection with new selections. Normaly when one of these executes you would disable the event handler of the other call during the change, so they don't keep triggering eachother in an infinite loop. The OnCollectionChanged edits the dataGrid, this would trigger the OnSelectionChanged which then edits the collection again etc. With the local function i cant disable the event handler in OnSelectionChanged

Comment: @BlackLotus: Why can't you do `selector.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;` or similar?

Comment: That i can, was more for the opposite, since OnCollectionChanged is a local function, i wont be able to disable it from within the OnSelectionChanged? resulting in a pointless trigger everytime the user selects a row?

Comment: @BlackLotus: `OnSelectionChanged` may also be a local function.

Comment: That is true, i'll have a play around with that and see wat a nice clean way is, don't wanna end up with a 200 line long method.

Comment: @BlackLotus: Just a hint, a local method may call other methods and pass parameters to them.

Comment: my appologies, was out of town. It worked than you very much @mm8

Comment: Thought selecting an answer as correct did this by default, fixed it now!