# How to create binding for SelectedItems of ListView and use the SelectedItems as the binding for another ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

everyone~

I'm trying to learn the **MVVM** pattern. I got a View and a ViewModel. In the view, I'd like to have two listviews. The first one is called `LVGroupMembers` which is used to show some AD group members of a group. The other one is called `LVSelectedMembers`, I'd like it to show the selected items of `LVGroupMembers` dynamically. I've managed to complete the binding for `LVGroupMembers` without a problem. But for the `LVSelectedMembers`, I don't have a clue how to make it happen. I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176949/binding-selecteditems-of-listview-to-viewmodel) might help, but I don't know how to do in my scenario exactly, Sorry.

Here're these two files:

the `View.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVMTEST.V.ShitV"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMTEST.V"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="LVGroupMembers" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupMembers}" />
        <ListView x:Name="LVSelectedMembers" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMembers}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

the `View` code behind:

```
public partial class ShitV : UserControl
{
    public ShitV()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ADGroupManagerVM adgroupManagerVM = new VM.ADGroupManagerVM();
        this.DataContext = adgroupManagerVM;
    }
}
```

the `ViewModel`:

```
class ADGroupManagerVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> GroupMembers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedMembers { get; set; }
    
    public ADGroupManagerVM()
    {
        GetGroupMembers();
    }
    
    public void GetGroupMembers()
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> _groupMembers = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ......
        GroupMembers = _groupMembers;
    }
    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: While you can bind the SelectedItem or SelectedValue property of a ListView (or the more simple ListBox) to a "single item" property in your view model, you can not do the same for the SelectedItems property. It is read-only. There are however workarounds, e.g. as shown in the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Actually, I did try to figure it out through the link to the duplicate question. Since I'm a beginner, I don't really know what should I do in my scenario. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: You could start by attaching a SelectionChanged event handler to the first ListBox, in which you update the SelectedMembers collection. Your view knows the view model, so that kind of access is ok from an architectural standpoint.

Comment: As a note, your ObservableCollection properties should be declared read-only. Otherwise their property setters should fire a change notification. Declare them like `public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedMembers { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();`

Comment: Also note that you would not use ListView as long as you do not set its View property. Use the simpler base class ListBox instead.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind tips. I'll try to start from these points. Have a nice day~